# Creating R package with Rcpp: errors

Tags: package, rcpp

I wanted to create my R package using the Rcpp library but I met some problems even with the example.

I run

> Rcpp.package.skeleton("foobar")

but when I try to compile/check the R package, I have the following error:

```
==> devtools::check(document = FALSE)
Setting env vars ---------------------------------------------------------------
CFLAGS  : -Wall -pedantic
CXXFLAGS: -Wall -pedantic
Building foobar ----------------------------------------------------------------
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save  \
  --no-restore --quiet CMD build "C:\Users\scacciat\Desktop\foobar"  \
  --no-resave-data --no-manual 

* checking for file 'C:\Users\scacciat\Desktop\foobar/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'foobar':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* cleaning src
* installing the package to process help pages
      -----------------------------------
* installing *source* package 'foobar' ...
** libs
g++ -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"\\icnas4.cc.ic.ac.uk/scacciat/R/win-library/3.2/Rcpp/include" -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
RcppExports.cpp:4:18: fatal error: Rcpp.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
Warning: running command 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="foobar.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="RcppExports.o rcpp_hello_world.o"' had status 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'foobar'
* removing 'C:/Users/scacciat/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpkvl6Bo/Rinst116c227323e9/foobar'
      -----------------------------------
ERROR: package installation failed
Warning: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/Rcmd.exe" INSTALL -l "C:\Users\scacciat\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpkvl6Bo\Rinst116c227323e9" --no-multiarch "C:/Users/scacciat/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpkvl6Bo/Rbuild116c5035785/foobar"' had status 1
Error: Command failed (1)
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

```

Comment: This doesn't seem correct. Try creating a new directory and then rebuild with `Rcpp.package.skeleton()`.

Comment: Nothing in our documentation suggests to use `devtools::check()`.  That said, that it breaks is likely your issue and not its, but I cannot really comment on a tool I do not use myself.

Comment: And `fatal error: Rcpp.h: No such file or directory` seems to indicate some issue with your system.

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to use a NFS or something and the compiler doesn't understand this path: `-I"\\icnas4.cc.ic.ac.uk/scacciat/R/win-library/3.2/Rcpp/include"`

Comment: To follow up on @DirkEddelbuettel's comment, even base R's `package.skeleton()` fails `devtools::check()` due to: 1. the `*-package.rd` needing to be modified, 2. description updates, and 3. bad examples. Though, one of the weird things is `name="anRpackage"` gets substitute everywhere when creating the `*-package.rd` vs. default `package.skeleton()`. Perhaps a bug worth fixing?

Comment: @Coatless: the [pkgKitten](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/pkgKitten/index.html) package does just that and creates packages that pass `R CMD check`.  It may even work with `devtools` though I never tried... ... and it does indeed work. (Though it leaves one `NOTE` regarding `Description:` meaning [pkgKitten](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/pkgKitten/index.html) may need a minor update too.)

Comment: And I just pushed an updated branch for Rcpp which does just that (as this wasn't actually a pkgKitten issue).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I was playing around with the issue on my own branch last night. It looks like the other pushed branch has only a fix for the function's spacing issue. I'll toss this in a github issue.

Comment: @Coatless Yes, let's take this to the rcpp-devel list or GH. It is no longer pertinent here.